# What does the lead vocalist sing in a Jam band show?

Tags: jam-band

I am learning about the "Jam band" genre and I understand these bands perform live shows that feature moments of improvisations.

I can easily imagine how the musicians play, sticking to a chord grid, improvising around scales etc... but what does the singer sing in these moments?

I am not asking for an extended list, but a few precise examples of famous lead singers occupations during jams would be nice.

Comment: I cant give you a specific example but in the early days of The Grateful Dead ( they never had a lead singer per say, )  pigpen, who sang many songs in their line up  would often improvise lyrics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varies by band.  Some, like Blues Traveller, have a lead singer that play an instrument, so they're involved in the jam.  Others grab a background instrument like a small percussion kit, tambourine or shaker and get involved in creating the groove.  Others are merely an extension of the audience and dance and move around, and still others simply walk offstage and relax or have themselves a pee break.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the jam band scene (I'm a big Umphrey's McGee fan) do bands like them (Phish, String Cheese Incident, Moe, Disco Biscuits etc.) don't have members that only do vocals. In fact their focus is on playing their instrument, that is where they shine and imho they are far better at that than singing. Sometimes I wish UM had a dedicated singer.